# Pushing changes to client using websockets Golang

Tags: javascript, go, websocket

I have been trying to push changes done on server side using websockets in Golang.

I have achived what i wanted by this code

Server side code:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "bufio"
)

type chat struct {
    message string
}

func (ms *chat) Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var reply string
    for {
         if reply !=  ms.message {
         websocket.Message.Send(ws, ms.message)
         }
         websocket.Message.Receive(ws, reply)
    }
}

func NewMessage(s *string){
   reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
   for {
       fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
       *s, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
       }
   }

func main() {
   myString := chat{"Welcome"}
   go NewMessage(&myString.message)
   http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(myString.Echo))
   http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}
```

Client side code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:1234");

    exampleSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log("connected");
    };

    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log(event.data);
        exampleSocket.send(event.data)
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = event.data;
    }


</script>
<h1>WebSockets</h1>
<form>
    <p id="p1" value="Hello, world!"/>
</form>
```

The problem with above code is repeatedly sending ms.message as `if reply !=  ms.message` does not work. Simply `var reply string` value is not being changed by `websocket.Message.Receive(ws, reply)`.

I have tried passing `reply` as a pointer but it does not update value on the client side dynamically.

Here is how server side would look like after the change:

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "bufio"
)

type chat struct {
    message string
}

func (ms *chat) Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var reply string
    for {
         if reply !=  ms.message {
         websocket.Message.Send(ws, ms.message)
         }
         websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &reply)
    }
}

func NewMessage(s *string){
   reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
   for {
       fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
       *s, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
       }
   }

func main() {
   myString := chat{"Welcome"}
   go NewMessage(&myString.message)
   http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(myString.Echo))
   http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}
```

This code does not fit my expectations.

Is it possible to dynamically update string on clients side without sending value multiple times as it is being done in the example number 1?

Comment: At first look you're ignoring the error in this line: `*s, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')` Also remember that each request will be handle for an individual goroutine so if you want to keep some global state you should use mutex or something to avoid race conditions.

Comment: I understand your point but i am trying to create a simple example which will help me later. I am planning to use channel or array of objects which are being changed dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply putting `websocket.Message.Receive` in the if statement fixes the problem.

```
package main

import (
   "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "bufio"
)

type chat struct {
   message string
}

func (ms *chat) Echo(ws *websocket.Conn) {
   var reply string
      for {
         if reply !=  ms.message {
            websocket.Message.Send(ws, ms.message)
            websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &reply)
         }

      }
}

func NewMessage(s *string){
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
for {
   fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
   *s, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
  }
}

func main() {
   myString := chat{"Welcome"}
   go NewMessage(&myString.message)
   http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(myString.Echo))
   http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}
```